# Call to undefined function logged_in()

Tags: php

I have a function `logged_in()` whose purpose is to check if the user is logged in. This function, located inside `users.php`, is called from `login.php`.

Everytime I attempt to call this function I get the following error

> Call to undefined function logged_in() in line 67

Here's my code

**users.php**

```
function logged_in() //line 67 
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}
```

**login.php**

```
if(logged_in()===true)
{
    include 'includes/widgets/loggedin.php';
}
else{
    include 'includes/widgets/login.php';
}
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Tip: when you include a file always include with an absolute path. Like: `include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/users.php")`. This will avoid any issues you might get from unresolvable relative includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include `users.php`. If you don't include that file you don't have access to any functions declared within it.:

```
<?php 
include('users.php');
if(logged_in()===true)
{
    include 'includes/widgets/loggedin.php';
}
else{
        include 'includes/widgets/login.php';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that users.php is included into login.php. Otherwise, it won't know that the function is there.

```
<?php 

include_once('users.php');
if(logged_in()===true)
{
    include 'includes/widgets/loggedin.php';
}
else{
        include 'includes/widgets/login.php';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to include or require the users.php file